# Why does one bitfield struct expression behave different across assignment?

Tags: c, gcc, embedded

Given an expression in C like:

```
foo = (<an expression>);
```

The compiler will often deign to assign the `foo` value multiple times. When `foo` is a register that controls hardware, that can lead to unexpected results. For example, I'm finding that expressions likes

```
foo = (struct Bar){.field1=13, .field2=42};

foo = Field1Value(13) | Field2Value(42);
```

will generate different sequences of updating foo. The second is generally pretty good about completing the rvalue and then assigning it. But the first often likes to update foo with multiple assignments. I have tried parentheses placement, but the optimizer seems to think otherwise.

*UPDATE*

What I wanted to understand is why these 3 statements had different results:

```
// 1
GCLK->CLKCTRL = (GCLK_CLKCTRL_Type){{.ID=GCLK_CLKCTRL_ID_TCC0_TCC1_Val, .GEN=GCLK_CLKCTRL_GEN_GCLK0_Val, .CLKEN=true}};
// 2
GCLK->CLKCTRL.reg = (GCLK_CLKCTRL_Type){{.ID=GCLK_CLKCTRL_ID_TCC0_TCC1_Val, .GEN=GCLK_CLKCTRL_GEN_GCLK0_Val, .CLKEN=true}}.reg;
// 3
GCLK_CLKCTRL_Type tmp = {{.ID=GCLK_CLKCTRL_ID_TCC0_TCC1_Val, .GEN=GCLK_CLKCTRL_GEN_GCLK0_Val, .CLKEN=true}};
GCLK->CLKCTRL = tmp;
```

The first was problematic. The second 2 work. I wanted to understand why. Obviously, the alternative way to do this kind of thing is with code like:

```
GCLK->CLKCTRL.reg = (GCLK_CLKCTRL_ID_TCC0_TCC1 | GCLK_CLKCTRL_GEN_GCLK0 | GCLK_CLKCTRL_CLKEN);
```

The GCLK global is a pointer to this structure def:

```
typedef struct {
  __IO GCLK_CTRL_Type            CTRL;        /**< \brief Offset: 0x0 (R/W  8) Control */
  __I  GCLK_STATUS_Type          STATUS;      /**< \brief Offset: 0x1 (R/   8) Status */
  __IO GCLK_CLKCTRL_Type         CLKCTRL;     /**< \brief Offset: 0x2 (R/W 16) Generic Clock Control */
  __IO GCLK_GENCTRL_Type         GENCTRL;     /**< \brief Offset: 0x4 (R/W 32) Generic Clock Generator Control */
  __IO GCLK_GENDIV_Type          GENDIV;      /**< \brief Offset: 0x8 (R/W 32) Generic Clock Generator Division */
} Gclk
```

where the `__IO` is a macro for `volatile` among other things.

Comment: If `foo` is a HW register, it should be defined as a pointer to `volatile`, which ensures the accesses to it to correspond the abstract machine flow.

Comment: can you provide an example?  you are not using bitfields are you?  not quite getting your syntax.  never use bitfields.  avoid structs across compile domains.  Please provide a simple example that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: In case of doubt, construct a temporary variable and assign to `foo` when done. If `foo` is marked `volatile`, this should work (but do check the generated assembly code).

Comment: @old_timer, I am playing with struct bitfields. I am not jumping compile domains, so I'm not worried about that. But that's an aside argument really, regardless of good idea/bad idea, I'm interested in it just for understanding sake.

Comment: Yes, I thought `volatile` would do the trick. The SAMD21 header files that I'm using seem to do the appropriate amount of `volatile` prefixing. So may be I'm just dealing with gcc "feature" when using bitfields. And *that* would be a good reason to avoid them. :)

Comment: If you provide more code we can eliminate the possibility of you misinterpreting something.

Comment: Agreeing with Eugene, with the understanding that "more code" should be a decent [mcve] right away.

Comment: I'll get a more explicit example, gonna take a bit to find the pieces though.

Comment: but the expressions above are not the same. First fills out different parts of 'foo'. the second modifies the whole foo. Not sure  what you even expected there.

Comment: If you want the compiler to do a single read, more than one modification, and then a write you need to code it that way.  using structs or bitfields then adding volatile to force the bus transfers rather than possibly sit in registers and not go to a memory interface, wont work.  the volatile will force each modification to do a read-modify-write.  so read then mask and shift, mask and shift, ..., then write...in the code...

Comment: okay, right you can make a copy into a matching struct, then do the manipulation there, then copy back to the volatile.  but what you are describing is crossing compile domains as you want to point this at a register that controls hardware, that is the particular compile domain to avoid.

Comment: **You should not care.** Read about [as if rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/As-if_rule). If you do care, code differently (perhaps with `volatile`, [atomic operations](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/atomic), etc...).

Comment: I am confused. But maybe you've answered my question. When I look at the first statement, in my mind, it should build up a struct Bar value from the two .field specifiers, and then when that is complete, assign the result into foo. But what you explain @Serge is not that. Is this just a nuance of bitfields I have never fully understood?

Comment: there is a fad going to use these ghee whiz features of C.  but in an unsafe and dangerous way.  implementation defined which just happens to work on my machine kind of thing.  the number of compilers being used has dropped of dramatically and the one/few happen to work for these bad habits, and they are not being reviewed or challenged.  and should.  Curious that we see two of these questions within 24 or 48 hours.

Comment: If you want to understand the difference create and post the disassembly and we can walk you through the parts you dont understand. (please use optimizations)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For accessing memory-mapped registers, always use pointer-to-`volatile` types, and always ensure that the pointed-to type is a basic type that can be accessed as a single unit on your hardware architecture. In particular do not use assignment of whole struct-type objects and do not use bitfields, since the C language does not strictly specify how they interact with `volatile`. You can use a volatle-qualified struct whose individual members have types that make sense to access as a unit, though. For example:

```
struct regs {
    uint32_t r1;
    uint16_t r2, r3;
};
volatile struct regs *myregs = (volatile void *)0xadd13000;
myregs->r1 = x<<24 | y;
myregs->r2 = z;
myregs->r3 = w;
```

The reason this works is that the C language requires that the number of accesses performed via volatile objects be equal to the number that would be performed on the "abstract machine" defined by the language, and that their order with respect to each other honor the order they have on the abstract machine.

Comment: Be wary of struct padding however. If there is padding, the struct layout may not correspond to the hardware register layout.

Answer (score 2):

> How to force C compiler to complete computation before assignment (?)

It should be sufficient to insure `foo` is of type `volatile`.  [@ Eugene Sh.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48287916/how-to-force-c-compiler-to-complete-computation-before-assignment/48288518#comment83560709_48287916)

```
volatile type_of_foo foo = Field1Value(13) | Field2Value(42);
```

---

An alternative would use 2 steps:

Assign the result to a safe, `volatile`, object that can be set many times, then assign to the register.

```
volatile type_of_foo foo_tmp = Field1Value(13) | Field2Value(42);

volatile type_of_foo foo = foo_tmp;
```

The compiler can assign, at the assembly code level, `foo_tmp` many times, yet cannot use that to assign `foo` until `foo_tmp` assignment is complete.

Pedantically, the `foo = foo_tmp;` itself, could in theory involve multiple assignments, but not likely.  Consider `_Atomic`, an option C feature for more ideas.

Comment: There is no reason whatsoever to make a temp variable volatile. If the actual register `foo` is not volatile, making the temp variable volatile does not help.

Comment: @R.. Rather than assert "no reason whatsoever ", perhaps ask for the rational? - Of which you may disagree.  `volatile` provides an improvement to OP's quandary with the reading of the `foo_tmp`.   `volatile` and reading of `foo` is not of issue here, just writing.  With the reading of `volatile foo_tmp`, that value must be finalized before-hand.  So at least 1 part of OP's goal is satisfied.  The assigned is a bit trickier as it likes needs to be done in an _atomic_ fashion.

Comment: "Atomic" in the sense that the term is used in the C language is not the issue here. Volatility is. With your version using the volatile temp, the final write to the actual register could still be duplicated or could be omitted entirely if the compiler can determine the result is never read back.

Comment: @R..  True `foo` should be `volatile` and that is not clear in the 2nd half.  The implication of the first half was not string enough,